# How do I remove curly braces from JSON strings using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, json, regex

Hi I have this JSON file I want to remove the curly braces from inside the strings in the chapters array, but if this curly braces contain more than 3 words (2 spaces inside the curly braces), I want the complete curly brace to be deleted. Is it possible **with Regular expression**?

```
 {
    "abbrev": "gn",
    "name": "Genesis",
    "chapters": [
        [
            "And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness {was} upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.",
            "And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.",
            "And God saw the light, that {it was} good: and God divided the light from the darkness. {the light from...: Heb. between the light and between the darkness}",
            "And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the evening and the morning were the first day. {And the evening...: Heb. And the evening was, and the morning was etc.}",
            "And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters, and let it divide the waters from the waters. {firmament: Heb. expansion}"
        ]
 ] }
```

I tried solving with negative look ahead, unsatisfactory results. And if its not possible with Regular expression what would be the solution for it in javascript?

Comment: Not possible with just regex. Loop over chapters, and use regex for pattern matching, and then you'll need to apply your custom logic (like count words, if words.length condition then do this) to manipulate the string

Comment: First of all, _do not_ try and do this by modifying your JSON in text form. Parse it, loop over the chapters, and then replace inside each individual string value only. Encode the result as JSON again, after you are done with the whole thing.

Comment: You can't appreciate Genesis until you've read it in its original JSON.  ;)

Comment: @CBroe Yes I meant that only, I was matching the strings by looping over chapters array. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't solve this using 2 regexes:

```
var regex1 = /{[^{}]+[ ][^{}]+[ ][^{}]+}/g;
var regex2 = /[{}]/g;

var str = ...;
str = str.replace(regex1, "");
str = str.replace(regex2, "");
```

Comment: This is not fully working. As per OP, it should remove `curly braces contain more than 3 words (2 spaces inside the curly braces)` but it is removing for a single space as well.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I just tested this on regex101 and it is working for me. Can you include a sample string that is being matched that shouldn't be matched or vice versa?

Comment: I created this fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/qprmbngu/. In this fiddle, you can see third string is misbehaving.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal Thank you! I have updated my answer, replacing my ".+"s with "[^{}]+"s. As far as I can tell, this is working perfectly now